# How to list books in an essay (in-text)?

Tags: lists

I would like to list in an essay three books that I read. I do not know how to do so in text.

Comment: Do you mean within the text, or as a bibliography? Do you have a style-guide you have to write this essay too, as style-guides tend to have firm, but differing, rules on references.

Comment: I do not have a style-guide, I am writing a Statement of Purpose and I want to list some of the books I used in a course, right now it looks like this:
"...alongside we studied the theory behind theme from diverse books, such as: Optical Coherence and Quantum Optics (Mandel & Wolf 1995); Quantum Optics (Scully & Zubairy 1997); and Laser Cooling and Trapping (Metcalf & Van der Straten 1999)".
But I do not know if this is correct.

Comment: Visit our sister site [writers.se]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should italicize (or underline in some cases) the book titles. This is true for nearly all scholarly journals and legal writing that I've seen. Most scholarly books I've read use italics as well.

> "...alongside we studied the theory behind them from diverse books, such as: *Optical Coherence and Quantum Optics* (Mandel & Wolf 1995); *Quantum Optics* (Scully & Zubairy 1997); and *Laser Cooling and Trapping* (Metcalf & Van der Straten 1999)."

However, it seems that the *New York Times* and other newspapers don't use italics because of something to do with AP computers and their inability to do italics. The *New York Times* quotes book titles.

Answer (score 0):

like this:
Last name, The author Middle name, Suffix. Title. Edition ed. Publication city:
(tab) Publisher, year. Print. Series name Series number.
Source noodletools.com

Comment: Says who? Where?